# List Where and IF different results C#

Tags: c#, list, where-clause

I got a list with 3495 results. And the code that I got has a loop within an IF condition. The loop is taking too long(about 8 minutes because is making another operations inside de if statement). What I want to do, is separate both results from de main list. But I got different list of ítems.

```
List <MyObjectType> myListOfObjects = GetAllMyStuff();
List <MyObjectType> myTrueListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();
List <MyObjectType> myElseListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();
int ifResults = 0;
int elseResults = 0;

myListOfObjects.ForEach( s => 
{
 if (s.SubSolicitud != null && s.SubSolicitud.Count() > 0)
     myTrueListObjects .Add(s);
 else
     myElseListObjects.Add(s);    
});

return;
```

Lets say that I got 3000 objects in the myTrueListObjects and 935 in the myElseListObjects .
But when I try to do with where expresión, I got different results

```
    List <MyObjectType> myIfListObjects = GetAllMyStuff();
    List <MyObjectType> myTrueListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();
    List <MyObjectType> myElseListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();

    myTrueListObjects =  myIfListObjects.Where( s = s.SubSolicitud != null   
                                                 && s.SubSolicitud.Count() > 0)
    myElseListObjects  = myIfListObjects.Where( s = !(s.SubSolicitud != null   
                                                   && s.SubSolicitud.Count() > 0))   
    return;
```

With these, I got 3935 in both lists (myIfListObjects and myElseListObjects) . I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Those statement do not seem valid.  Are you missing => and :

Comment: Don't `new List<MyObjectType>` if you are going to just replace the object with the results of a `Where`. Second: `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which should give a compiler error unless you `.ToList()` to get a `List<MyObjectType>`.

Comment: dont use count() == 0 use false == any()

Comment: Your code should work (ignoring the missing ">" and ".ToList()") - are you sure, the where-conditions are exactly as posted? BTW - it's correct to have all objects in myIfListObjects and myElseListObjects (and none in myTrueListObjects), if the condition in fact applies for no object...

Answer (score 0):

This code here should return the same than your first piece of code. I have tried with a simple list and it works. Your sintaxis was wrong, I was not able to build it.

```
List <MyObjectType> myIfListObjects = GetAllMyStuff();
List <MyObjectType> myTrueListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();
List <MyObjectType> myElseListObjects = new List<MyObjectType>();

myTrueListObjects =  myIfListObjects.Where( s => (s.SubSolicitud != null   
                                             && s.SubSolicitud.Count() > 0)).ToList();

myElseListObjects  = myIfListObjects.Where( s => (!(s.SubSolicitud != null   
                                               && s.SubSolicitud.Count() > 0))).ToList();

return;
```